# The easiest and most right way to stick 'New!' icon on portfolio gallery images

Tags: css, position

how do I stick 'New' icon on a more of 200x200 image in portfolio using CSS? do I have to use position absolute? if so, it won't look the same on all screens?

however, this is what I am looking for:

[image: newicon]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/04cedd5d5c6bec5b00379415c983bbb9.png))</sub>

Can you see the new blue icon on the first image? that's what I need.
I need an explanation on how to stick it exactly like this without cropping it with the image.

What is the best way?

Comment: i hate the hall monitors on SO. this is a great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to set its `position` to `absolute` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/923af/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageholder">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40&text=NEW" class="new" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageholder {
  position: relative;
}

.new {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, I am using boostrap container and row class (with span3) will it affect?

Comment: I don't think it will have any impact on this

Comment: THnak you ill try it right away

Comment: Worked, thanks! I had to use top: -15px though, does that matter? cause it was a bit under instead of being above it